# How create multidimensional string array in managed C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, managed

In **managed** **C++/CLI** we create an array of string like below :

```
cli::array<String^> ^arr = gcnew cli::array<String^>{};
```

Now how create multidimensional string array in managed C++/CLI?
Mean:

```
string[][]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// 3 rows, 2 colums, that is rank 2    
array<String^,2>^ ar = gcnew array<String^,2>(3,2);
ar[0,0] = "row 0, column 0";
ar[2,0] = "row 2, column 1";
```

As an alternative you can use jagged arrays

```
// 3 rows
array<array<String^>^>^ ja = gcnew array<array<String^>^>(3); 
// Last row with 2 members
ja[2] = gcnew array<String^>(2);
ja[2][1] = "row 2, column 1"
```

But jagged arrays are defined different in C#